# Proof? of irreducibility of cyclotomic polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, complex-numbers, irreducible-polynomials, cyclotomic-polynomials

Let $\omega = e^{\frac{i2\pi}{n}}$.

---

I am trying to show that the minimal polynomial of $\omega$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is the cyclotomic polynomial, that is the polynomial whose roots are the **primitve** $\text{nth}$ roots of unity.

---

**My attempt**

Let $f(x)$ be the minimal polynomial we are looking for.

Now it is clear that $\mathbb{Q[\omega]}=\mathbb{Q}[\omega^{k}]$ iff $\text{gcd}(k, n)=1$

(*****Edit:***  THe next line is incorrect and basically that is the entire problem of irreducbility**)

So, $\omega \to \omega^{k}$ for $\text{b}$ as above, gives rise to a field automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}[w]$ which fixes $\mathbb{Q}$. So, $f(\omega^{k})=0$

now we also know that these are the only possible possible field automorphisms that preserve $\mathbb{Q}$.

Also, if $f(\beta)=0$

then $\mathbb{Q}[\omega]=\mathbb{Q}[x]/ f(x) = \mathbb{Q}[\beta]$ where equality is upto field isomorphism.

However here I am stuck. I am not able to show that $\beta$ is a **primitive** nth root of unity.

I wanted to prove the irreducibility of cyclotomic polynomial from scratch so if someone can help me along the lines of my attempt or point out that my attempt is wrong or not fruitful please do so.
I know there are several proofs of this fact but I am trying to do one myself.

Comment: I struggled with this problem myself for quite a while, but never got to a solution. I. N. Herstein's Topics in Algebra gives two equivalent problems, both marked "**" for difficulty. The first (sec. 5.3 #8) adds the note "This is a well-known theorem. I know of no easy solution, so don't be disappointed if you fail to get it. If you get an easy proof, I would like to see it." The second (sec. 5.7 #13-15) gives some hints, but I couldn't get the existence of the key automorphisms.

Comment: Speaking of, why do you say $\omega \to \omega^k$ gives a field automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}[w]$? This is true if $\omega^k$ is a root of the minimal polynomial of $\omega$, but that's more or less exactly what we'd like to prove.

Comment: Indeed, this is a notoriously non-trivial result. For a look at a few proofs, see [this write-up](https://www.lehigh.edu/~shw2/c-poly/several_proofs.pdf) by Steven H. Weintraub. Of course, if $n$ is prime, you can show that the minimal polynomial is $n$-Eisenstein and hence irreducible by Gauss's Lemma.

Comment: @Carlo Thanks for the link! And the proofs aren't nearly as bad as I feared. Though I still wonder about Herstein's suggestion to prove it via showing there exist automorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$ mapping a primitive root to any other primitive root. It's certainly equivalent, but doesn't seem close to any of those proofs.

Comment: @aschepler, I believe I have shown in my proof that the minimimal poly. of  $\omega$ has all the primitve roots of unity. THe problem is that i need to show that these are all the roots of the minimal polynomial.

Comment: @aschepler $\omega \to \omega^k$ is an automorphism if $(k,n)=1$ because both $\omega$ and $\omega^k$ generate the same field as both generate all the roots of unity. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @SubhamJaiswal I'm not seeing how such an automorphism is certain to exist. But if you have shown it does, since $\omega$ is a root of the cyclotomic polynomial, its minimal polynomial is a factor of the cyclotomic in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, so cannot have roots other than the primitive roots of unity. (To show the cyclotomics $\Phi_n(x)$ are in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, we have $\prod_{d|n} \Phi_d(x) = x^n-1$.)

Comment: @aschepler Yes, I just need to show that $\omega \to \omega^k$ is a field automorphism and the rest follows from what you said.

Comment: @aschepler You r right my map is not well defined and basically that is the entire problem of irreduciblity.